# Flickering video problems on with Windows 10 and HDMI cable

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

I have just bought a new GTX 1050 card but since my monitor doesn't have an HDMI input I used an HDMI-to-DVI cable only to find out some fullscreen apps flicker and make the screen go blank over and over again. I tried the same cable-GPU configuration on another PC with Linux and it worked just fine even on the same apps and games. I finally solved it by using a regular DVI cable.

I made sure both have the correct drivers installed. Why does Windows have this problems?

Comment: Could be anything. Have you tried a different monitor?

Comment: It's probably not Windows. Try a different monitor to see if the problem persists. If it does, it's most certainly the cable that's causing that problem. Use another cable to fix it.

Comment: Although the cable is the most likely culprit, there's a possibility the problem lies with the HDMI port on the GPU..

Comment: As I said before, the same cable and GPU work just fine on another PC with Linux, in fact, I even tried with another GPU (an old 660) on the same windows machine and it flickered too, whereas on Linux it didn't, using the same cable in all cases.